# Multiselect jQuery plugin with good mobile support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that overrides the default behaviour/appearance of a select element with the multiple attribute.

```
<select multiple>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

All I care about is that there's a dropdown list instead of the default window where multiple items are visible at the same time, and that it has good mobile support.

I've been using the popular [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin. I like the style of it but don't really need the search capabilities because I have a limited number of options that can be easily scrolled, plus it does not officially support mobile and I'm running into buggy mobile behaviour with it.

Just wondering if there's a good alternative that meets these requirements? Maybe [Bootstrap-Multiselect](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.12) or one of [these other options](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/multiselect/)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used `Chosen` as well, but since it doesn't support mobile we moved to [Select2](https://select2.github.io/).

> Select2 gives you a customizable select box with support for
>   searching, tagging, remote data sets, infinite scrolling, and many
>   other highly used options.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').select2();
</script>
```

Comment: Any idea why Chosen seems to be the most popular when it doesn't support mobile while Select2 seems to do what Chosen does and more, plus it supports mobile as you say?

Comment: @Kevin, good name.  Your guess is good as mine.  My assumption is that they don't time to make it support mobile.  Maybe someone will eventually fork it, and add support.  But for now, I'd go with `Select2`

Comment: They say "full browser support for all modern and legacy browsers", so modern would include mobile or modern mobile I guess? Have you had a chance to do any of your own testing?

Comment: I just read [this](http://www.devproblems.com/3-of-the-best-javascript-searchable-select-boxes-compared-select2-vs-chosen-vs-selectize-js-performance/) article that says while Chosen is the best in terms of performance, Select2 has more options and is better maintained.

Comment: My own testing with `Chosen`?  If it's in mobile, it will regress to the basic select list (so it will be a popin, essentially).  You lose all the features that come with using `Chosen`

Comment: No sorry, I meant testing with Select2.